# count of subset with given sum

Tags: java, recursion

I was trying to find a way to give back the count of subsets that are equal to the sum. the array would include 5 numbers. I wrote a code that at the end counts all the branches instead of the correct subsets that are equal to the sum and I can't find out how to change it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment4 {

    public static int countSubsetSums(int[] arr, int sum) {
        return countSubsetSums(arr,sum, 0);
    }

    public static int countSubsetSums(int[] arr, int sum, int i) {
        int count=0;
        if(sum==0) {
            count++;
        }
        else if(i >= arr.length) {
            return count;
        }
        else {
            if(sum>=0) {
                count= countSubsetSums(arr, sum- arr[i], i++) + countSubsetSums(arr, sum, i++);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers into array");
        int [] myArr= new int [5];
        for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
            myArr[i]= myScanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter a number into sum");
        int sum= myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(countSubsetSums(myArr,sum));

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a dynamic programming question. Check this for the implementation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-subsets-with-sum-equal-to-x/

Comment: my array needs to be a arr[] and not two dimension. i saw that link but couldn't find a way to amplify what i saw there to my code

Comment: Could you provide an example? (expected input -> expected output)

Comment: Enter 5 numbers to array
1 2 3 4 5
Enter a number into sum
8
Output:3

Enter 5 numbers to array
1 2 3 4 5
Enter a number into sum
20
Output:0

Comment: No, the code in the provided link is just fine, the multidimensional array is a part of the solution, not your input. I don't think there's strict need for dynamic programming though, this can be done naively - with exponential complexity - as quoted by the provided link. With such a small set you can calculate all possible sums, and then count how many are equal to the one you want.

Comment: the form of my solution must include:
public static int countSubsetSums(int[] arr, int sum) 

public static int countSubsetSums(int[] arr, int sum, int i) 

and not any other options.....

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic was mostly right, but the base cases were a little off (fixed code below):

If i is out of bounds or sum is negative, then there is no subsets that sum to the given sum starting past i, so we return 0.

If the sum is equal to 0, then there is only one subset of arr that equals sum which is the empty subset (assuming arr elements are strictly positive. If arr can include 0s, then this is a totally different problem).

Lastly, if a[i] is less than sum, then we can add the count of subsets that use a[i] else we just counts subsets without a[i]

```
public static int countSubsetSums(int[] arr, int sum) {
    return countSubsetSums(arr,sum, 0);
}

public static int countSubsetSums(int[] arr, int sum, int i) {
    if (i >= arr.length || sum < 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (sum == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int count=0;
    if (arr[i] <= sum) {
      count = countSubsetSums(arr, sum - arr[i], i+1);
    } 
    count += countSubsetSums(arr, sum, i+1);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! apparently my problem was that i couldnt do i++ but had to do i+1